# loading number of CSVs to one dataset for neural network training for signal transformation y1(x) -> y2(x)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to build a neural network for signal transformation: `y1(x) - > y2(x)` using TensorFlow and Keras as main instruments.

**I want to prepare a training dataset from files which are stored separately and my question for now is how to do it efficient way?**

**DATA**
I have a lot of data  - more than one million files
each CSV file represents a case: it contains the following columns:

> y1 | x_val | Z1 | Z2 | ... | y2

where Z1 | Z2 -  additional columns that can be used as features for the training of NN in future.

**So the main idea is to train NN using `y1` and `x_val` as inputs  predict `y2` as output.**

I use the next *code to build a dataset from separate files*:

```
# Define the path to the input and output data
input_path = 'data/marked/'

# Get the list of input files
input_files = os.listdir(input_path)
# lists for dataset handling
input_data = []
output_data = []

for i, file in enumerate(input_files):
    # Read the input data and output from the CSV file
    df = pd.read_csv(input_path + file)
    # Select the needed columns for the input data
    # Reshape the input data to fit the neural network input
    input_data_from_csv = df[['y1','x_val']].values.T
    
    input_data.append(input_data_from_csv)
    # Append the output data to the list
    output_data.append(df['y2'].values)

# Convert the lists to numpy arrays
X = np.array(input_data)
y = np.array(output_data)

print(type(X))
print(type(y))
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

print("Memory size of numpy array X in bytes:", X.size * X.itemsize)
print("Memory size of numpy array y in bytes:", y.size * y.itemsize)

# splitting the dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

# print(X_train)
```

It works fine if I work with a small amount of data - e.g. 1000 files ok.

I understand that if I will have a large number of files in my data folder - the data will not fit in the memory of the notebook?
How to handle that question?

Does the Tensorflow has special dataset objects that can be loaded into memory by slices and optimized for load, saving and work with large dataset?

E.g. - how can I do the same I am doing simple lists but using TensorFlow functionali?

I can see the official documentation (e.g. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) but it seems unclear to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Not yet. any suggestions?

Comment: For a project where I have to load 17K images for blood cell classification, I used successfully [`Sequence`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) to load data on demand.

Comment: Or maybe more simple [`CsvDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset)